# Need Help related to Inbound Calling in Open CTI

Tags: apex, opencti, twilio

I follow all the steps and also able to make successful inbound call using the library

https://github.com/choppen5/TwilioSalesforceClick2Dial

Here We set one page for respone which is

https://github.com/choppen5/TwilioSalesforceClick2Dial/blob/master/Respond.vf

```
<apex:page showheader="false"
     sidebar="false"
     cache="false"
  contentType="text/xml"
  >{! '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>' }
<Response> 
    <Dial><Client>salesforce_agent</Client></Dial>
</Response>
</apex:page>
```

Here all inbound call will dynamic linked to an Agent and they get a popup on there screen.But I am not sure how Salesforce select Agent dynamically here. If we have multiple agent then what we need to do here. if I enter mobile number here then call got connected to user but Salesforce Open CTI library doesn't invoke. I want to assign call dynamically to user and at the same time use the feature of open CTI library (Display record of contact)

Comment: Would also love to see a working example of inbound calling to Salesforce